# Findbugs Bug SE_BAD_FIELD on boolean field

Tags: java, jenkins, findbugs, serializable

We have Findbugs configured to run on our Jenkins via Maven.

Among other things it complains about SE_BAD_FIELD on the following code line:

```
private boolean logged = false;
```

The [description of this bug](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SE_BAD_FIELD) says

> **Se: Non-transient non-serializable instance field in serializable
>   class (SE_BAD_FIELD)**
>
> This Serializable class defines a non-primitive instance field which
>   is neither transient, Serializable, or java.lang.Object, and does not
>   appear to implement the Externalizable interface or the readObject()
>   and writeObject() methods.  Objects of this class will not be
>   deserialized correctly if a non-Serializable object is stored in this
>   field.

But `boolean` is a primitive!? So why is it complaining? Or is this some kind of Findbugs, Maven or Jenkins Bug?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your Jenkins workspace and running a maven clean? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Can you post the full class? Or at least those sections of your class that are needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have noticed that FindBugs sometimes reports the wrong line number for SE_BAD_FIELD. So you might want to check the other fields for serializability instead. (I use FB 1.3.9.). If the problem persists, please post all fields.

Comment: @Thomas That seems to be it! There was another field which actually had that problem! Please post the comment as an answer so I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that FindBugs sometimes reports the wrong line number for SE_BAD_FIELD. So you might want to check the other fields for serializability instead. (I use FB 1.3.9.).