# FindBugs does not report any line number for SE_BAD_FIELD

Tags: sonarqube, findbugs

I was using the FindBugs plugin (v3.1) in SonarQube. There is an issue raised for rule SE_BAD_FIELD.

For this one, no line number is been raised by the plugin, where the message field contains the variable name that caused the issue.

Is there any configuration needed to be done for getting the line number or it's a known problem.

Comment: That's a [known one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12089659/1005481).

Comment: problem is that in the class file, there are only line number attributes for methods, not fields.